# "Your passcode is required to enable Touch ID". often appears when I return to the computer and forces me to restart

Tags: macos

Mac Book Air 2020
Monterey 12.2.1

This annoying problem seems random.  It does not seem to happen depending on when I last used the machine.  Or whether the lid is shut. I have fiddled with the settings in System Prefs Users and Groups, Touch ID, Password, and Privacy.
I tried getting help from Apple.
Generally the machine works just fine while I am using it.

Comment: Why does that force you to restart? It behaves similarly to the iPhone, requires the password periodically.